# Add an icon with jQuery to selector on click

Tags: jquery, css

I have a FAQs page set up to show the answers when the questions are clicked.  Here's [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soncraig/nqgzL/) with an identical setup.  I'd like to add a upward triangle when an answer is visible, but I can't get it to work right.  I've tried everything from pure CSS to jQuery, and I just can't get it to work right.  Any ideas?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="faqs">
    <h3 class="question">Question 1? <span class="faqsIcon" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#9660;"></span></h3>
    <div>
        <p class="answer">Answer 1</p>
    </div>
    <h3 class="question">Question 2? <span class="faqsIcon" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#9660;"></span></h3>
    <div>
        <p class="answer">Answer 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the jQuery: (from http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-sliders)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#faqs h3').each(function() {
        var tis = $(this), state = false, answer = tis.next('div').slideUp();
        tis.click(function() {
            answer.slideToggle(state);
            tis.toggleClass('active', state);
            $(this).find('span.faqsIcon').data('data-icon',"&#9650;");
        }); // end click function
    }); // end faqs a_function
}); // end ready
```

Comment: How I'd do it -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nqgzL/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the CSS (though your content was an `&` not `▲`), but that the `toggleClass()` method wasn't working, replacing that with the following, works:

```
tis.toggleClass('active');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nqgzL/3/).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  Is there any way that I can animate that transition with a fade in/out?

Comment: Not reliably; I think Firefox can animate the pseudo-elements, but so far as I know the other browsers don't allow it as yet. You could use a span with `color: transparency` and use `transition` to animate to `color: black` on `:hover` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this CSS :

```
.question.active:before {
    content: "\25B2  ";
    padding-right: 3px;
}
```

If the question is active, there is this triangle before : ▲

Answer (score 0):

Remove the flase parameter on your toggleClass call:

```
tis.toggleClass('active');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nqgzL/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want.  You can toggle that class, but it may not give you exactly what you want since you'll need 2 classes.  I used javascript solely.

I set an attribute **active** inside each h3 and retreived it every time.  Fun fact: Don't put boolean values in because they will be re-interpreted as strings.

```
if (active) $(this).find('span.faqsIcon').html("&#9650;");
else $(this).find('span.faqsIcon').html("&#9660;");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DzrdG/